# When enable Block HTML output from Cache CMS Widget show previous data

Tags: blocks, cache, magento-1.9.3.2

When I Disable  Blocks HTML output my Widget working good but when i enable     Blocks HTML output it shows wrong or previous output.

Actually my theme shows category from widget and i facing this issue

URL:**http://www.onlineprojectdemo.net/shop_popus/index.php/categories/health-supplement.html**

ScreenShot[image]

Comment: Can you specify your problem in detail, means actualy which output it need to show instade of current output because current output is not proper.

Comment: when you select any category under product it must shows their sub category but instead of that it shows only one type of category in every category page which shown in sidebar and this happen when i enable BlockHTMLOutput cache if i disable that cache then it is working fine @DhirenVasoya

Comment: Have you check this block code? Which is done for this sidebar?

Comment: yes it is working perfectly if I disable Block HTML output from Cache @DhirenVasoya

Comment: the problem occure when i enable cache of Block HTML

Comment: I means the code which is done in phtml file or block file of that file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64283/discussion-between-jaimin-and-dhiren-vasoya).